# Why are my div's margin affected by content/blocks INSIDE of it?

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<div>
    <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

or:

```
<div>
    some content
</div>
```

Without the:

```
<p>some content</p>
```

...the div's positioning is different. It appears as though block content INSIDE the div is affecting the div's outer (top) margin. So is the div pushed down? I would think that content inside the div, like a block would not affect the containing block's margin.  Why is the margin of the div affected by the content inside of it?

Answer (score 13):

You're talking about [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

See: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/vgJxX/

You can "fix it" by adding to the parent element:

- A `border`.
- Some `padding`.
- `position: absolute`.
- `float: left`.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <p>I'm doing the "broken" thing you hate.</p>
</div>

<div id="d2">
    <p>I'm not!</p>
</div>

<div id="d3">
    <p>Neither am I!</p>
</div>

<div id="d4">
    <p>Me neither!</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    background: #ccc
}
p {
    margin: 20px 0
}

#d2 {
    border: 1px solid red
}

#d3 {
    padding: 1px
}

#d4 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: You can also use [`:before`/`:after` to fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15007326/107152).

Answer (score 3):

Because of [margin collapsing](http://complexspiral.com/publications/uncollapsing-margins/).  Add a border or padding to your `div`.