# Clear fix and uncollapse margins with CSS without side effects?

Tags: css, css-float, margin

What's a *general* good way to clearfix and uncollapse margins with CSS without side effects (nor additional HTML elements)?

The following cause side effects (and would like to avoid them):

- Setting `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto`:
  Clips `box-shadow`, CSS transforms, and other content one may want to show outside the box. Thus it can't be used in several cases (but otherwise works great).
- Setting `border` or `padding`: Obvious positioning/sizing effects.

Comment: The funny thing about `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` is that clipping content is the whole point of using that property... the fact that it resolves floats is the real side effect.

Comment: @BoltClock, equally funny as border and padding with regard to margin collapse.

Answer (score 5):

The clear and collapse fix, based on [this clear fix](http://perishablepress.com/new-clearfix-hack/), with added margin uncollapse:

```
.group:before, /* :before to uncollapse the top margin */
.group:after{
    display: block;
    clear: both; /* clear fix */
    content: "\a0 "; /* &nbsp; - just a space doesn't uncollapse margins */
    visibility: hidden; /* make sure not to show anything */
    height: 0;
}
.group{
    zoom: 1; /* solves it all for IE < 8, and doesn't hurt other browsers */
}
```

**Demo**: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQb49/), [IE7 render with netrenderer](http://netrenderer.com/?render&browser=ie7&voffset=0&go=1&url=http://jsfiddle.net/cQb49/show)

Note that `content: "\a0 ";` is equivalent to `&nbsp;` and is used instead of a non-whitespace character (eg `.`) so that when you select the block and copy it, you do *not* get extra visible characters, which otherwise happens in some browsers (for example IE9).

The drawbacks with this solution are:

- `:before` and `:after` are defined, so special care needs to be taken if they are to be used.
- For every new selector you want to have this fix applied to you have to specify the selector 3 times.
- Not very short/trivial.

A similar solution is used by [YUI, described in this article](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/) (but without `&nbsp;`).

Comment: This clearfix technique requires less CSS:  http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: @cimmanon, nice, using `display: table` instead of `block` simplifies it. That should probably be another answer here, feel free to post it.

Comment: ***the root of all margin-collapsing evil*** ;P https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/mistakes , also looked at this: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ – It is certainly shorter but not sure if it has some downsides.